# Could someone correct my conception of electricity?

Tags: electrons, potential, voltage

I am trying to learn about electricity but I have some questions.

So far my understanding of electricity is that electrons are full of potential energy and they lose it to move. Like I said this potential energy is converted to kinetic energy (which makes the electrons move), thermal energy, light energy etc. The potential energy they lose (per unit charge) is the voltage.

Could someone say if what I just said is true? Also, in a circuit with a battery and a resistor, the potential energy lost in the resistor is the same as the potential energy of the battery. How do electrons still have energy to move after the resistor?

Answer (score 2):

The best adjustment I can think of to help you is to recognize that potential energy of those electrons *comes from* the electric field.  The electrons aren't swelling with energy, ready to burst at the seams.  It's more like a surfer rising up on wave, where the wave provides the potential energy the surfer needs to go forward.  However, the general direction you were thinking does line up well with how it really works.

When it comes to batteries and resistors, remember that those devices are *real* components.  A battery is not quite an ideal voltage source, so when you really start peering at those details, expect odd things to come up.  There will be small resistances in the battery, and the electrons will still have a little extra potential energy as they reach the battery.

One other thing that may be useful: electricity at the macroscopic level is caused by the statistical movement of lots of electrons, and while the electrons are moving in quasi-random directions at nearly the speed of light, the forward bias of electron movements is actually quite slow!  In many cases the average movement is less than 1m/s!

This is very analogous to how waves in the ocean work.  Individual molecules of water do not rush forward towards the beach at the speed of the wave.  They stay relatively motionless (or move up and down), as they transmit the *energy* of the wave forward at much higher speed.  You've seen this if you've ever tried to move a boat or small object on the surface of the water by pushing it with waves.  The object hardly moves, even though the waves move quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's all correct.

In an ideal circuit, where wires have no resistance, electrons lose all their energy in the resistor, but ideal circuits are only a model. A real circuit has also a (hopefully) small wire resistance to take into account.